# mysql group duplicates based on title and description

Tags: php, mysql

Indeed.com groups duplicate job postings by title and description.  [Here](http://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=html&l=San+Francisco,+CA&rbt=Front-end+Engineer+-+Web+Developer+-+Javascript+-+UI+-+PHP&rbc=CyberCoders+Engineering&jtid=d63d0b5da4899d4c&jcid=cf00d3a3bfa3f5a7&filter=0&grp=tcl) is an example of what I am talking about. How would I go about doing something like that?  Is it just a simple `Group By` statement or something else entirely?

Comment: Could you please provide an example schema that you are working with?

Answer (score 1):

It **could** be done with a simple group by, but that will only group exact matches.

There are several parameters you can test to determine whether to group entries. In their example: company name, location, and keywords.

"Something else entirely" would involve analyzing the fields of one row to determine their similarity to another row.  I think this would probably be too processor intensive to integrate on a large-scale.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're looking at in the example.  But it wouldn't really make sense to do a sql group on something like description.  That would cause a ton of overhead, especially with the amount of data indeed is keeping track of.

A good way to store data similar to what indeed stores would be with document index, try googling solr or nosql.

Comment: If you just look at the 2 main listings you will see they are the exact same but from different job boards (duplicates).

Comment: Aah, no, that's probably not done using a group by statement.  It would kill their db and grouping is used for aggregation anyway.  Other types of data indexes (like solr) have all sorts of algorithms to make document searching more effective.  Things like only storing root words, storeing synonyms, not storing common words, and document deduping (what you're looking for).  It doesn't have the best online documentation, but check out this link: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Deduplication, if you're serious about doing something like indeed you should think about different storage methods.